# SharePoint / IIS - HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: iis, sharepoint

Having issues connecting to any of our SharePoint sites, with the below error happening for all users.

*HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.*

When i look at the Application Pools, i can see that some of them are stopping after a few mins, due to the Rapid-Fail Protection. When i check the errors in the Event Viewer, i get the below error every second that the App Pools are running.

*The Module DLL C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.*

I've restarted the server, restarted all services and app pools, even tried replacing the .dll with a similar one from another server and registerting it, but nothing is working. Google gives me next to no info when i search for that specific dll, only giving some tips on reinstalling certain features of IIS.

Its a Windows 2012 R2 and SharePoint 2013, both out of support i know. Added the event viewer error details below.

---

```
- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Microsoft-Windows-IIS-W3SVC-WP 
   [ Guid]  {670080D9-742A-4187-8D16-41143D1290BD} 
   [ EventSourceName]  W3SVC-WP 

- EventID 2280 
   [ Qualifiers]  49152 
   Version 0 
   Level 2 
   Task 0 
   Opcode 0 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
 
 - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2023-10-17T10:14:12.000000000Z 
   EventRecordID 8199595 
   Correlation 
  
- Execution 
   [ ProcessID]  0 
   [ ThreadID]  0 
   Channel Application 
   Computer **machinename** 
   Security 

- EventData 
  ModuleDll C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll 
   7F000000 

--------------------------------------------------------------------

Binary data:

In Words
0000: 0000007F    

In Bytes
0000: 7F 00 00 00
```

Comment: You need to go to the Details tab in that Event Viewer error to see what is exact the error data said in the error message. Without that, there isn't anything to discuss further. Besides, which SharePoint version and Windows Server version also matter. Anyway this isn't about programming (but server administration), so off topic on this site.

Comment: Added the server details and error above.

Comment: `0x0000007F` is unfortunately a very bad error code that might be related hardware failure. As both the Windows and SharePoint releases are all end of life, I assume you should get rid of them completely and move on.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so we found the issue yesterday. KB5031407 (October 10, 2023—KB5031407 (Security-only update) patch was installed over the weekend, and for whatever reason, it completely broke IIS. Uninstalling the patch seems to have resolved the error.

Will be migrating it to a new server this month, so better get on that.

Thanks all for the suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

The error "The Module DLL C:\windows\System32\inetsrv\cachuri.dll failed to load. The data is the error." is related to the cachuri.dll module, which is used by the URL Rewrite module in IIS.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1,Check if the cachuri.dll file exists in the C:\windows\System32\inetsrv directory. If it is missing, you can try copying it from another server with the same version of IIS installed.

2,Check if the URL Rewrite module is installed on the server. If it is not installed, you can try installing it from [there](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

3,If the URL Rewrite module is already installed, you can try repairing it using the Programs and Features control panel.

4,If none of the above steps work, you can try uninstalling and reinstalling the URL Rewrite module.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/cloud-services/dev-http-error-503-cannot-access-website#troubleshooting-steps

Comment: I installed URL rewrite there, but it doesn't seem to have fixed it.